# Do we have a guideline for posters to follow when tagging their posts?

Tags: discussion, tags

The reason I am concerned is that I started  with removing the "professionalism" tag when there is no content in the post that has anything to do with "professionalism". Then I noticed that some posters were festooning their posts with tags. The cumulative impact, when people search by tag, is of course, not pretty.

Here is one example:

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33333/career-advice-is-it-time-to-quit-software-engineering

This individual had five tags including the overused "professionalism" tag. I also took out his "work environment" tag. In his case, the only tag that's relevant is "career development".

On one hand, I am not happy when posters overtag. On the other hand, it's easier for me to clean up when a poster puts up too many tags than when a poster is not adding a tag that they should be including.

Comment: Its one thing to remove unnecessary tags from new questions. another to substitute your judgement for the communities judgement on older questions.  I would recommend starting a thread to ask about removing the tag from any question more than a couple weeks old.

Comment: I also want to point out this question: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/227/16 where the community resoundly voted down the idea that professionalism tag should not be used.  Professionalism is the correct tag for "ettiqute in the workplace" type questions.

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame "resoundingly voted down" with one downvote? No kidding.

Comment: And that 10 upvotes for the top answer.

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame Now, it's 8. 8 out of the 25 users in mata. Or even more impressive, a very representative 8 out of several hundred users in the community at large.

Comment: And yet it is the majority opinion.  Like I said if you want to revise it then ask your own meta question do not go off on your own personal crusade.

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame 8 out 25 is not a majority by any stretch of the imagination. Nor is 8 out of several hundreds. Try harder.

Comment: So create a new question and see if the opinion has shifted.  
As it stands the community wants the tag and it is inapproriate for one individual to take it upon themself to change the way the site has worked for 2 years.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan by your reasoning, you *also* don't have a majority to change it, so the status quo is the default.  We do not require a strict majority of account-holders before making a change; if we did, we'd never get anything done.  The votes on that question seem pretty clear to me in support of the tag.  Feel free to start a new meta post; you could argue that that post is two years old and we should revisit, for instance.

Comment: But in the meantime, if the tag is being applied in accordance with its tag wiki (which isn't always the case), then that's correct and shouldn't be changed.  If you find *incorrect* uses of it -- incorrect according to the wiki and the site, not incorrect according to your opinion -- then by all means remove those.

Answer (score 5):

The general goals are:

- Use all applicable tags (the limit is five, and not one or two, for a reason)
- Be consistent; if similar questions do (or don't) use a particular tag, follow that lead so tag searches don't become useless

That said, no site's tag set is static and ours could do with some review and cleanup.  For individual questions, if you think a retagging is in order, go for it.  If you notice a pattern, please bring it to meta (as has been done, inconclusively so far, for [professionalism](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professionalism)).